# Android WebView: Display only half of a webpage

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Currently I have a HTML page with a container containing element A on the left side and element B on the right side. I'm trying to view this page using ViewPager with two tabs ie. have only half of the webpage displayed on Tab1 and the other half on Tab2. This makes it so that even if the user chooses to scroll all the way on Tab1, he can never see the content on the right side unless he swipes to Tab2. The size can be determined by 0-50% and 51% - 100% horizontally if possible.

Any idea how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Android webview is a kind of browser, it will behave the same as another bowser is doing for showing webpage, as per your requirement ask your Web development team to make it browser compatible, and check their output in Chrome, Firefox browser in your device then integrate into Android Webview.

Comment: It is already browser compatible though, there is no problem in displaying it on Chrome for example. What I require is the android webview selectively displaying only a portion of the webpage, is that possible?